# Are there UNIX variants or other OS which make user level threads visible to OS kernel?

Tags: multithreading, thread, hyperthreading

Are there UNIX variants or other OS which make user level threads visible to OS kernel ?

Comment: That does not make sense.  The kernel maintains userspace, it can control anything it want in userspace.  The kernel exists without userspace, but we still build a userspace for the purpose of making things easier to reason about.  The kernel is not something you *want* to perform more things, you want it to perform as little number of things as possible.  The question: is what do you want to achieve?

Comment: If by "user level threads" you mean [green threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads) or [coroutines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine) or similar mechanisms, then you're asking a nonsense question. The whole point of these non-kernel multiprocessing mechanisms is that they are not kernel multiprocessing mechanisms. Promoting them that way would ruin much of their advantage.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're asking is whether user threads are scheduleable entities in the kernel. Whether the user thread is "visible" to the kernel depends on the mapping between user -> kernel, which depends on the model used. There are various threading models -

- mx1 - all user threads map to 1 kernel thread
- mxn - m threads map to
  n kernel threads.
- 1x1 - 1 user thread maps to 1 kernel thread

[https://www.kernel.org/doc/ols/2002/ols2002-pages-330-337.pdf][1] for info on threading models.

The default threading model on Linux `(<glibc 2.4)` is **LinuxThreads** which used 1x1. Each thread has a different pid here.
LinuxThreads was not posix compatible, so a new threading model was implemented - **NPTL** `(man pthreads(7) for more info)`. In **NPTL** (1x1), all user threads in a process have the same pid, but have unique thread ids.
These can be seen using the -L flag in ps `(man ps(1))`

nice article on NPTL -- [https://www.redhat.com/whitepapers/developer/POSIX_Linux_Threading.pdf][2]

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, yes I did read up on the thread models and I do want to know if there exist any OS which allow user thread scheduling because I want to see if there is one OS then does it provides performance advantage to multithreaded applications running on multicore systems ?

Comment: If you're referring to the case where the library does scheduling (mx1, mxn), these models were discontinued for performance and implementation reasons. You may still be able to use these on Linux if you use the older model. Irrespective of the model (newer models such as MPTL may work better) MT should give you better performance on multi core - if your app is designed right and can make use of MT (this applies to all OSes).